# Does Chrome reloadButton ignores the cache?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

I am using Chrome and monitoring the http connections. I load a page and the response returned by the server contains

```
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Expires: Thu, 18 Jul 2013 14:51:22 GMT
```

Therefore, I would not expect Chrome to make a request to the server when I try to reload this page. However, when I press the Reload button, I see a new connection to the server which in turn returns the same page with a new expiration date for the cache.

Anyone has an explanation?

**EDIT**

Here is the request and response that I receive each time that I press the reload button (except that the time for `Date`, `Expires` and the value of `CF-RAY` in the response changes every time)

*Request*

```
GET /mobile_13.xml HTTP/1.1
Host    triton.karnaval.com
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie  __cfduid=d518a34eae859853e9a8dbfb6eb4078ed1366655468
```

*Response*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 14:51:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Expires: Thu, 18 Jul 2013 14:51:19 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
CF-RAY: 8f7bfeaf5f50697
Content-Encoding: gzip

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
...
```

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of network log? Are there any 304 not modified logs?

Comment: No, the server returns a 200 with the entire xml. I edited my question to add the detailed request and response

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Chrome intentionally "busts the cache" by setting max-age to 0 when you click "Reload". See the source here: [ResourceFetcher.cpp:676](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/fetch/ResourceFetcher.cpp&q=ReloadIgnoringCacheData&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=676)

```
if (isReload || frameLoadType == FrameLoadTypeSame || request.isConditional() || request.httpMethod() == "POST")
    return ReloadIgnoringCacheData;
```

and here: [FrameLoader.cpp:1176](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/loader/FrameLoader.cpp&q=max-age%20reload&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=1176)

```
if (request.cachePolicy() == ReloadIgnoringCacheData) {
    if (m_loadType == FrameLoadTypeReload)
        request.setHTTPHeaderField("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
```

(I think these are the right spots, I'm not super-familiar with the Chromium code.)